# 2x2 Chess Board

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm writing a 2x2 chess board. I have the code working where I press down it goes down but say I'm in the bottom grid I want to disable this button how do I go abouts doing that as I ant to disable certain buttons for certain grids but not the same buttons for all the grids

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


public class assignment1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

        JPanel board, buttons;

        JLabel G1, G2, G3, G4;

        JButton B1, B2, B3, B4, B5, B6, B7, B8, B9;

        ImageIcon i1 = new ImageIcon("Images/pawn.jpg");
        ImageIcon a1 = new ImageIcon("Images/left_up.png");
        ImageIcon a2 = new ImageIcon("Images/up.png");
        ImageIcon a3 = new ImageIcon("Images/right_up.png");
        ImageIcon a4 = new ImageIcon("Images/left.png");
        ImageIcon a5 = new ImageIcon("Images/reset.png");
        ImageIcon a6 = new ImageIcon("Images/right.png");
        ImageIcon a7 = new ImageIcon("Images/left_down.png");
        ImageIcon a8 = new ImageIcon("Images/down.png");
        ImageIcon a9 = new ImageIcon("Images/right_down.png");

    public static void main(String[]args){

        assignment1 frame = new assignment1();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public assignment1() {

        super("Chess Board");

                Container c = getContentPane();
                c.setLayout(new GridLayout (2,3));

            board = new JPanel();
            board.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,4,4));
            JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
            buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,2,2));

            G1 = new JLabel(i1);
            G1.setBackground(Color.white);
            G1.setOpaque(true);
            G1.setIcon(i1);

            board.add(G1);

            G2 = new JLabel(i1);
            G2.setBackground(Color.black);
            G2.setOpaque(true);
            G2.setIcon(null);

            board.add(G2);

            G3 =  new JLabel(i1);
            G3.setBackground(Color.black);
            G3.setOpaque(true);
            G3.setIcon(null);

            board.add(G3);

            G4 = new JLabel(i1);
            G4.setBackground(Color.white);
            G4.setOpaque(true);
            G4.setIcon(null);

            board.add(G4);

            c.add(board);
            //c.add(board.BorderLayout.NORTH);
            c.add(buttons);

            B1 = new JButton(a1);
            buttons.add(B1);

            B2 = new JButton(a2);
            buttons.add(B2);

            B3 = new JButton(a3);
            buttons.add(B3);

            B4 = new JButton(a4);
            buttons.add(B4);

            B5 = new JButton(a5);
            buttons.add(B5);

            B6 = new JButton(a6);
            buttons.add(B6);

            B7 = new JButton(a7);
            buttons.add(B7);

            B8 = new JButton(a8);
            buttons.add(B8);

            B9 = new JButton(a9);
            buttons.add(B9);

            B1.addActionListener(this);
            B2.addActionListener(this);
            B3.addActionListener(this);
            B4.addActionListener(this);
            B5.addActionListener(this);
            B6.addActionListener(this);
            B7.addActionListener(this);
            B8.addActionListener(this);
            B9.addActionListener(this);

            setVisible(true);
            setSize(500,500);

    }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


                //if statement for Grid 1 Button 6 Right
                if (G1.getIcon() == i1)
                {
                    if(e.getSource() == B6)
                    {
                        G1.setIcon(null);
                        G2.setIcon(i1);
                    }
                }

                //if statement for Grid 1 Button 9 Right_down
                if (G1.getIcon() == i1)
                {
                    if(e.getSource() == B9)
                    {
                        G1.setIcon(null);
                        G4.setIcon(i1);
                    }
                }

                //if statement for Grid 1 Button 8 Down
                if (G1.getIcon() == i1)
                {
                    if(e.getSource() == B8)
                    {
                        G1.setIcon(null);
                        G3.setIcon(i1);
                    }
                }

                //if statement for Grid 2 Button 4 Left
                if(G2.getIcon() == i1)
                {
                    if(e.getSource() == B4)
                    {
                        G2.setIcon(null);
                        G1.setIcon(i1);
                    }
                }

                //if statement for Grid 2 Button 7 left Down
                if(G2.getIcon() == i1)
                {
                    if(e.getSource() == B7)
                    {
                        G2.setIcon(null);
                        G3.setIcon(i1);
                    }
                }

                //if statement for Grid 2 Button 8 Down
                if(G2.getIcon() == i1)
                {
                    if(e.getSource() == B8)
                    {
                        G2.setIcon(null);
                        G4.setIcon(i1);
                    }
                }

                //if statement for Grid 3 Button 2 Up
                if(G3.getIcon() == i1)
                {
                    if(e.getSource() == B2)
                    {
                        G3.setIcon(null);
                        G1.setIcon(i1);
                    }
                }

                //if statement for Grid 3 Button 6 right
                if(G3.getIcon() == i1)
                {
                    if(e.getSource() == B6)
                    {
                        G3.setIcon(null);
                        G4.setIcon(i1);
                    }
                }

                //if statement for Grid 3 Button 3 right Up
                if(G3.getIcon() == i1)
                {
                    if(e.getSource() == B3)
                    {
                        G3.setIcon(null);
                        G2.setIcon(i1);
                    }
                }

                //if statement for Grid 4 Button 2 Up
                if(G4.getIcon() == i1)
                {
                    if(e.getSource() == B2)
                    {
                        G4.setIcon(null);
                        G2.setIcon(i1);
                    }
                }

                //if statement for Grid 4 Button 4 Left
                if(G4.getIcon() == i1)
                {
                    if(e.getSource() == B4)
                    {
                        G4.setIcon(null);
                        G3.setIcon(i1);
                    }
                }

                //if statement for Grid 4 Button 1 Left Up
                if(G4.getIcon() == i1)
                {

                    if(e.getSource() == B1)
                    {
                        G4.setIcon(null);
                        G1.setIcon(i1);
                    }
                }

                //reset Button
                if (e.getSource() == B5)
                {
                    G1.setIcon(i1);
                    G2.setIcon(null);
                    G3.setIcon(null);
                    G4.setIcon(null);
                }

            }
        }
```

Comment: You mention "bottom grid" and buttons like we know what you're talking about. Please describe your problem and your program in greater detail. Assume that we are completely ignorant about your problem.

Comment: Also consider using arrays and for loops to *greatly* simplify your code.

Comment: Don't assume we are completely ignorant about your problem, believe it.

Comment: @peeskillet: I see no problem with a 2x2 board. Start simple and then expand. I do want to know more about his code and problem though.

Comment: Not sure if i got you right, but seriously where are you ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I know I'm a bit late with this one and I probably should have gotten back a little earlier than now but I wanted to share my code that I got working just in case there are any body else that wanted to make a chess board well I only made a 2x2 but you could probably expand on from this

```
//importing java swing and awt to help program work
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;


    public class assignment1 extends JFrame implements ActionListener  {

            //declaring the JPanel, JLabel and JButton's Globally
            JPanel board, buttons;

            JLabel grid1, grid2, grid3, grid4;

            JButton button1, button2, button3, button4, button5, button6, button7, button8, button9;

            //Declaring images globally
            ImageIcon pawn = new ImageIcon("Images/pawn.png");
            ImageIcon arrow1 = new ImageIcon("Images/left_up.png");
            ImageIcon arrow2 = new ImageIcon("Images/up.png");
            ImageIcon arrow3 = new ImageIcon("Images/right_up.png");
            ImageIcon arrow4 = new ImageIcon("Images/left.png");
            ImageIcon arrow5 = new ImageIcon("Images/reset.png");
            ImageIcon arrow6 = new ImageIcon("Images/right.png");
            ImageIcon arrow7 = new ImageIcon("Images/left_down.png");
            ImageIcon arrow8 = new ImageIcon("Images/down.png");
            ImageIcon arrow9 = new ImageIcon("Images/right_down.png");

        public static void main(String[]args){

            assignment1 frame = new assignment1();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        }

        public assignment1() {

            super("Chess Board");

                    Container c = getContentPane();
                    c.setLayout(new GridLayout (2,2));

                //setting up new JPanel for board to display the 4 grids
                board = new JPanel();
                board.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,2,4,4));
                JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
                buttons.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3,2,2));

                //setting up grid1
                grid1 = new JLabel(pawn);//placing the image in the background of the grid
                grid1.setBackground(Color.white);
                grid1.setOpaque(true);
                grid1.setIcon(pawn);//displaying image

                //adding grid1 to the board
                board.add(grid1);

                //setting up grid2
                grid2 = new JLabel(pawn);//placing the image in the background of the grid
                grid2.setBackground(Color.black);
                grid2.setOpaque(true);
                grid2.setIcon(null);//setting icon to null

                //adding grid2 to the board
                board.add(grid2);

                //setting up grid3
                grid3 =  new JLabel(pawn);//placing the image in the background of the grid
                grid3.setBackground(Color.black);
                grid3.setOpaque(true);
                grid3.setIcon(null);//setting icon to null

                //adding grid3 to the board
                board.add(grid3);

                //setting up grid4
                grid4 = new JLabel(pawn);//placing the image in the background of the grid
                grid4.setBackground(Color.white);
                grid4.setOpaque(true);
                grid4.setIcon(null);//setting icon to null

                //adding grid4 to the board
                board.add(grid4);

                //adding board to the container
                c.add(board);
                //adding buttons to the container
                c.add(buttons);

                //Creating button 1 and adding an image to Button 1
                button1 = new JButton(arrow1);
                buttons.add(button1);
                button1.setEnabled(false);//hard setting the button so that the start up will disable this button

                //Creating button 2 and adding an image to Button 2
                button2 = new JButton(arrow2);
                buttons.add(button2);
                button2.setEnabled(false);//hard setting the button so that the start up will disable this button

                //Creating button 3 and adding an image to Button 3
                button3 = new JButton(arrow3);
                buttons.add(button3);
                button3.setEnabled(false);//hard setting the button so that the start up will disable this button

                //Creating button 4 and adding an image to Button 4
                button4 = new JButton(arrow4);
                buttons.add(button4);
                button4.setEnabled(false);//hard setting the button so that the start up will disable this button

                //Creating button 5 and adding an image to Button 5
                button5 = new JButton(arrow5);
                buttons.add(button5);
                button5.setEnabled(false);//hard setting the button so that the start up will disable this button

                //Creating button 6 and adding an image to Button 6
                button6 = new JButton(arrow6);
                buttons.add(button6);
                button6.setEnabled(true);//hard setting the button so that the start up will enable this button

                //Creating button 7 and adding an image to Button 7
                button7 = new JButton(arrow7);
                buttons.add(button7);
                button7.setEnabled(false);//hard setting the button so that the start up will disable this button

                //Creating button 8 and adding an image to Button 8
                button8 = new JButton(arrow8);
                buttons.add(button8);
                button8.setEnabled(true);//hard setting the button so that the start up will enable this button

                //Creating button 9 and adding an image to Button 9
                button9 = new JButton(arrow9);
                buttons.add(button9);
                button9.setEnabled(true);//hard setting the button so that the start up will enable this button

                //method for button 1
                button1.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
            {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonOne)
                {
                    firstButtonPerformed(buttonOne);
                }
            });

                //method for button 2
                button2.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonTwo)
                {
                    secondButtonPerformed(buttonTwo);
                }
            });
                //method for button 3
                button3.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonThree)
                                {
                                    thirdButtonPerformed(buttonThree);
                                }
            });
                //method for button 4
                button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonFour)
                                {
                                    fourthButtonPerformed(buttonFour);
                                }
            });
                //method for button 5
                button5.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonFive)
                {
                    fifthButtonPerformed(buttonFive);
                }
            });
                //method for button 6
                button6.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonSix)
                {
                    sixthButtonPerformed(buttonSix);
                }
            });
                //method for button 7
                button7.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonSeven)
                {
                    seventhButtonPerformed(buttonSeven);
                }
            });
                //method for button 8
                button8.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonEight)
                {
                    eightButtonPerformed(buttonEight);
                }
            });
                //method for button 9
                button9.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent buttonNine)
                {
                    ninethButtonPerformed(buttonNine);
                }
            });


                setVisible(true);
                setSize(500,500);

        }
            public void firstButtonPerformed(ActionEvent buttonOne)

            {
                //if statement for Grid 4 Button 1 Left Up
                if(grid4.getIcon() == pawn)
                {
                    if(buttonOne.getSource() == button1)
                        {
                            grid4.setIcon(null);
                            grid1.setIcon(pawn);

                            button1.setEnabled(false);
                            button2.setEnabled(false);
                            button3.setEnabled(false);
                            button4.setEnabled(false);
                            button5.setEnabled(false);
                            button6.setEnabled(true);
                            button7.setEnabled(false);
                            button8.setEnabled(true);
                            button9.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }//end of if statement
                }

                public void secondButtonPerformed(ActionEvent buttonTwo)
                {
                    //if statement for Grid 3 Button 2 Up
                    if(grid3.getIcon() == pawn)
                    {
                        if(buttonTwo.getSource() == button2)
                        {
                            grid3.setIcon(null);
                            grid1.setIcon(pawn);

                            button1.setEnabled(false);
                            button2.setEnabled(false);
                            button3.setEnabled(false);
                            button4.setEnabled(false);
                            button5.setEnabled(false);
                            button6.setEnabled(true);
                            button7.setEnabled(false);
                            button8.setEnabled(true);
                            button9.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }//end of if statement

                    //start of else if statement for button 2 for grid 2
                    else if(grid4.getIcon() == pawn)
                    {
                        if(buttonTwo.getSource() == button2)
                        {
                            grid4.setIcon(null);
                            grid2.setIcon(pawn);

                            button1.setEnabled(false);
                            button2.setEnabled(false);
                            button3.setEnabled(false);
                            button4.setEnabled(false);
                            button5.setEnabled(true);
                            button6.setEnabled(true);
                            button7.setEnabled(false);
                            button8.setEnabled(true);
                            button9.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }//end of if statement
                }

            public void thirdButtonPerformed(ActionEvent buttonThree)
            {
                //if statement for Grid 3 Button 3 right Up
                    if(grid3.getIcon() == pawn)
                    {
                        if(buttonThree.getSource() == button3)
                        {
                            grid3.setIcon(null);
                            grid2.setIcon(pawn);

                            button1.setEnabled(false);
                            button2.setEnabled(false);
                            button3.setEnabled(false);
                            button4.setEnabled(true);
                            button5.setEnabled(true);
                            button6.setEnabled(false);
                            button7.setEnabled(true);
                            button8.setEnabled(true);
                            button9.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }//end of if statement
            }

            public void fourthButtonPerformed(ActionEvent buttonFour)
            {
                //if statement for Grid 2 Button 4 Left
                    if(grid2.getIcon() == pawn)
                    {
                        if(buttonFour.getSource() == button4)
                        {
                            grid2.setIcon(null);
                            grid1.setIcon(pawn);

                            button1.setEnabled(false);
                            button2.setEnabled(false);
                            button3.setEnabled(false);
                            button4.setEnabled(false);
                            button5.setEnabled(false);
                            button6.setEnabled(true);
                            button7.setEnabled(false);
                            button8.setEnabled(true);
                            button9.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }//end of if statement

                    //start of else if statement for button4 for grid 3
                    else if(grid4.getIcon() == pawn)
                    {
                        if(buttonFour.getSource() == button4)
                        {
                            grid4.setIcon(null);
                            grid3.setIcon(pawn);

                            button1.setEnabled(false);
                            button2.setEnabled(true);
                            button3.setEnabled(true);
                            button4.setEnabled(false);
                            button5.setEnabled(true);
                            button6.setEnabled(true);
                            button7.setEnabled(false);
                            button8.setEnabled(false);
                            button9.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }//end of else if statement
            }

            public void fifthButtonPerformed(ActionEvent buttonFive)
            {
                //reset Button if statement
                    if (buttonFive.getSource() == button5)
                    {
                        grid1.setIcon(pawn);
                        grid2.setIcon(null);
                        grid3.setIcon(null);
                        grid4.setIcon(null);

                        button1.setEnabled(false);
                        button2.setEnabled(false);
                        button3.setEnabled(false);
                        button4.setEnabled(false);
                        button5.setEnabled(false);
                        button6.setEnabled(true);
                        button7.setEnabled(false);
                        button8.setEnabled(true);
                        button9.setEnabled(true);
                    }//end of reset button if statement
            }

            public void sixthButtonPerformed(ActionEvent buttonSix)
            {
                //if statement for Grid 1 Button 6 Right
                    if (grid1.getIcon() == pawn)
                    {
                        if(buttonSix.getSource() == button6)
                        {
                            grid1.setIcon(null);
                            grid2.setIcon(pawn);

                            button1.setEnabled(false);
                            button2.setEnabled(false);
                            button3.setEnabled(false);
                            button4.setEnabled(true);
                            button5.setEnabled(true);
                            button6.setEnabled(false);
                            button7.setEnabled(true);
                            button8.setEnabled(true);
                            button9.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }//end of if statement

                    //start of else if statement for button6 for grid4
                    else if (grid3.getIcon() == pawn)
                    {
                        if(buttonSix.getSource() == button6)
                        {
                            grid3.setIcon(null);
                            grid4.setIcon(pawn);

                            button1.setEnabled(true);
                            button2.setEnabled(true);
                            button3.setEnabled(false);
                            button4.setEnabled(true);
                            button5.setEnabled(true);
                            button6.setEnabled(false);
                            button7.setEnabled(false);
                            button8.setEnabled(false);
                            button9.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }//end of else if statement
            }

            public void seventhButtonPerformed(ActionEvent buttonSeven)
            {
                //if statement for Grid 2 Button 7 left Down
                    if(grid2.getIcon() == pawn)
                    {
                        if(buttonSeven.getSource() == button7)
                        {
                            grid2.setIcon(null);
                            grid3.setIcon(pawn);

                            button1.setEnabled(false);
                            button2.setEnabled(true);
                            button3.setEnabled(true);
                            button4.setEnabled(false);
                            button5.setEnabled(true);
                            button6.setEnabled(true);
                            button7.setEnabled(false);
                            button8.setEnabled(false);
                            button9.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }//end of if statement
            }

            public void eightButtonPerformed(ActionEvent buttonEight)
            {
                //if statement for Grid 1 Button 8 Down
                    if (grid1.getIcon() == pawn)
                    {
                        if(buttonEight.getSource() == button8)
                        {
                            grid1.setIcon(null);
                            grid3.setIcon(pawn);

                            button1.setEnabled(false);
                            button2.setEnabled(true);
                            button3.setEnabled(true);
                            button4.setEnabled(false);
                            button5.setEnabled(true);
                            button6.setEnabled(true);
                            button7.setEnabled(false);
                            button8.setEnabled(false);
                            button9.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }//end of if statement

                    //start of else if statement for button 8 grid4
                    else if (grid2.getIcon() == pawn)
                    {
                        if(buttonEight.getSource() == button8)
                        {
                            grid2.setIcon(null);
                            grid4.setIcon(pawn);

                            button1.setEnabled(true);
                            button2.setEnabled(true);
                            button3.setEnabled(false);
                            button4.setEnabled(true);
                            button5.setEnabled(true);
                            button6.setEnabled(false);
                            button7.setEnabled(false);
                            button8.setEnabled(false);
                            button9.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }//end of else if statement
            }

            public void ninethButtonPerformed(ActionEvent buttonNine)
            {
                //if statement for Grid 1 Button 9 Right_down
                    if (grid1.getIcon() == pawn)
                    {
                        if(buttonNine.getSource() == button9)
                        {
                            grid1.setIcon(null);
                            grid4.setIcon(pawn);

                            button1.setEnabled(true);
                            button2.setEnabled(true);
                            button3.setEnabled(false);
                            button4.setEnabled(true);
                            button5.setEnabled(true);
                            button6.setEnabled(false);
                            button7.setEnabled(false);
                            button8.setEnabled(false);
                            button9.setEnabled(false);
                        }
                    }//end of if statement
            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {

            }
        }
```

I hope this helps anybody that needs it

Answer (score 0):

Add to actionPerformed function : before every action check you curent position, so if it's left bottom when you press f/e. button 2 nothing should happen.
Or I didn't get your question.

Answer (score 0):

You keep a note of where the pawn is

```
 int x=0, y=0;
```

When you move the pawn, you check if x is == 1, if it is then you disable the right hand buttons, if it == 0 then you disable the left.  then you do the same with y.

Just make sure and update them every time you move.

```
 //change x and y based on button clicked

 if (x==1)
 {
  //disable right buttons & enable left
 }
 else if (x==0)
 {
 //disable left buttons & enable right
 }

 if (y==1)
 {
  //disable down buttons & enable up
 }
 else if (y==0)
 {
 //disable up buttons & enable down
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> I ant to disable certain buttons for certain grids but not the same
>   buttons for all the grids

`GridLayout` with Component's `left-to-right` orientation it lay outs the component with the order you are adding. So For a `2x2`  gird:

```
 jPanel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));

 jPanel1.add(button1); //button1 is at grid (1, 1)
 jPanel1.add(button2); //button2 is at grid (1, 2)
 jPanel1.add(button3); //button3 is at grid (2, 1)
 jPanel1.add(button4); //button4 is at grid (2, 2)
```

So, to finds a component at grid cell `(row, col)` and work with it, it is actually easy:
First, find the index of the component and then ask `jPanel1` to return it:

```
GridLayout layout = (GridLayout) jPanel1.getLayout();
int numCol = layout.getColumns();
int index = (row-1)*numCol + col-1; 

if(index < jPanel1.getComponentCount())
    jPanel1.getComponent(index).setEnabled(false);
```